# How to write user specific views?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-users

I have a written views in django where i have more than one tab on the web page. Some of them I want to make invisible for those user whose is_staff status is False. Following is the code

```
   TOP_NAVIGATION_BAR = [ {'name':'home', 'href':'/my_app/home',active:False},
                          {'name':'Content', 'href':'/my_app/content',active:False},
                          {'name':'Secure', 'href':'/my_app/Secure',active:False},
                        ]

   class topnavigationbar:
         tab = TOP_NAVIGATION_BAR
         def set_active_tab(self, tab_name):
             for tab in self.tabs:
                if tab['name'] == tab_name:
                   tab['active'] = True;
                else:
                   tab['active'] = False;

         def __init__(self, active_tab):
             self.set_active_tab(active_tab)
```

For every view i set the top_navigation_bar active option= True.

Now I want that Secure tab should not be visible to users whose is_staff status is False.
How and where can i write the query for that?
Thanks

Comment: What is this class? Why is it a class? Where is it used?

Comment: this class is used to pass into base template which tab is active

Comment: That doesn't answer my question. *How* are you "passing it into the base template"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution (involving not modifying the arguments to `__init__()`, which may be troublesome) is to define which URLs need `is_staff` in `TOP_NAVIGATION_BAR`, like this:

```
TOP_NAVIGATION_BAR = [
    {{'name': 'Secure', 'href': '/my_app/Secure', active: False, secure: True},
    ...
]
```

Now, you can carry out the check itself in the template (assuming your navigation menu appears in the template as the `nav_menu` context variable):

```
{% for menu_item in top_menu %}
{% if not menu_item.secure or request.user.is_staff %}
    <a href='{{ menu_item.href }}' ...
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get `request.user` as `user` parameter in template (if you are using `RequestContext`). This you can use to decide in your base/menu/header template to hide or show the tab.